# Microsoft Graph - How to get associated files with the security alert "Unusual volume of file deletion"

Tags: security, graph

Using security/alerts in Microsoft Graph can sometimes show an alert with the title "Unusual volume of file deletion".

I cannot see, using Graph, the files that were affected by this alert. How would I gather that information through Graph?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way through graph to pull information about specific files that are affected. If the Graph Security API does not provide sufficient detail you can use the Office 365 Security and Compliance center [here](https://protection.office.com), to view and manage your alerts and actions.
Here's the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/alert-policies?view=o365-worldwide#managing-alerts) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Jackson - there is a link to source information which does point towards the office compliance centre so I guess I'll use that if need be.